# How to use dependencies from another Module with Dagger2 in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

So i Have AppModule and HomeModule.
I would like to use in HomeModule the Application context and AppDatabase from AppModule.

I'm getting this error: `AppDatabase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method. public abstract interface HomeComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [AppModule::class]
)
interface AppComponent {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    fun build(): AppComponent

    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder
}
}
```

This is the AppModule:

```
@Module
class AppModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideAppDatabase(app: Application): AppDatabase{
    return Room.databaseBuilder(
        context,
        AppDatabase::class.java,
        "app_db"
    )
        .build()
}

}

@Module
```

How can i use the AppModule dependencies(in this case AppDatabase and the Application) in the HomeModule ?

```
@Module
class HomeModule {

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHomeDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): HomeDao {
    return appDatabase.homeDao
}

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideHomeRepository(homeDao: HomeDao): HomeRepository {
    return HomeRepositoryImpl(homeDao)
}
}
```

The HomeComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [HomeModule::class]
)

interface HomeComponent {
    fun inject(homeFragment: HomeFragment)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not work because they are unrelated to each other.
The solution is:

The **HomeComponent**:

```
@FragmentScope
@Subcomponent(
    modules = [HomeModule::class]
)

interface HomeComponent {
    fun inject(homeFragment: HomeFragment)
}

@Scope
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
annotation class FragmentScope
```

Explanation: We should use **HomeComponent** as *subcomponent* for **AppCompnent** and we should use another *annotation* to avoid conflict.

The **AppComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AppModule::class])
interface AppComponent {

    fun getHomeFragmentCompnent():HomeComponent

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun build(): AppComponent

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
    }
}
```

Then in your Fragment you can use it like this, for example:

```
@FragmentScope
class AnyFragment:Fragment {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dao: HomeDao 

    //in onCreateView
    val component = ((application as YourApplcation).applicationComponent)
        .getHomeFragmentCompnent().inject(this)
}
```

Comment: This works, isn't another way instead of calling `(requireActivity().application as App).appComponent.homeComponent().inject(this)` in the fragment?just wondering